# No way to see custom object Created Date in Lightning Setup?

Tags: lightning, setup

I'm used to SF Classic, where you can go to a custom objects page and see the **Created By** field which provides the person and date. There is also the **Last Modified** field which provides a person and date.

This data does not seem to be present in Lightning as I go digging for it. Have they just completely hidden this useful info from the Lightning UI?

Comment: answer not accepted ? =P

Comment: @glls haha sure I'll accept your answer if you like, but it doesn't really solve the question, just agrees with my own conclusion (that there is no way to see the object's Created By / Last Modified By data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fields should be there, you just need to go to the Page Layouts for the object in question (under the Object Manager) , and it should have the info you are looking for:
[image]

As you mentioned, if the page layout is deleted and a new one created, then you will not be able to see the date creation of the object unless you switch back to classic. I suggest you create an Idea at https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch

Comment: Those fields show the dates for the Page Layout, not the object itself. That might work if you know for certain the original layout is still there. But how can I be sure the layout(s) are the ones created at the same time as the object?

Comment: you are right, if the page layout is deleted, then the last page layout creation date will be the one displayed, you would then have to check for record created dates, and if those are deleted, there is no more to it =(